# GitHub Action errors because it can't see a folder

Tags: github, testing, continuous-integration, github-actions, godot

I'm trying to set up my first GiHub Action. All it needs to do is run a test over my Godot files. I based it on a template.

```
name: CI

on:
  pull_request:
    branches: [ main ]
  workflow_dispatch:
  
jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - name: godot-tester
      uses: croconut/godot-tester@v2.5
      with:
        version: 3.4
        release_type: stable
        # Give relative path to your project.godot, if not in top level of repo
        path: app
```

The action errors every time, when trying to find the project file.

```
/entrypoint.sh: line 166: cd: ./app: No such file or directory
```

[image: A screenshot of the error]

The folder, app, is there and it contains the project. I've tried with or without a trailing slash, it makes no difference.

[image]
[image: The app folder, showing the project file]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you need to access the files from the proper repository in a Github Actions workflow, you need to setup the [actions/checkout](https://github.com/actions/checkout) first.

This will allow the workflow to access the **Github workspace** (which is basically the repository root).

In your case, the workflow should look like this:

```
name: CI

on:
  pull_request:
    branches: [ main ]
  workflow_dispatch:
  
jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v3
    - name: godot-tester
      uses: croconut/godot-tester@v2.5
      with:
        version: 3.4
        release_type: stable
        # Give relative path to your project.godot, if not in top level of repo
        path: app
```

The `actions/checkout` action has a default behavior, but you can also configure other fields to customize what you want it to do. Check the [action README page](https://github.com/actions/checkout) to see all the possibilities.